# How To Hide The Visual And Html Editor Completely?

Tags: visual-editor, html-editor

I have some clients that are going to be using wordpress for their sites.  I created custom fields for them to input data in so they don't have to use the editor.  How do I hide the page editor completely?  I want it completely hidden so they don't accidentally muck things up. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For posts:

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');
function my_custom_init() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor' );
}
```

[See Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support). For custom post types that you register, you can specify what 'features' it supports when you [register it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) it use the 'supports' arguments.

For custom post types that are not registered by you can use the above with 'post' replaced by the custom post type name.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative, rather than removing the editors, they are simply hidden from use for anyone who is not an Administrator.

I prefer hiding, rather than removing. I'm sure there are cases for both.

```
//Hide New Post Options from all except Administrator
function hide_post_page_options() 
{
    if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )
        return;

    $hide_post_options = '<style type="text/css"> .postarea { display: none; }</style>';
    print($hide_post_options);
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'hide_post_page_options'  );
```